# Trouble with asynchronous events in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

The code I have loops through 10 items in an array, makes a request for each item, then pushes the returned data to an array. Everything runs fine until the `$q.all` line.

```
details.getDetails = function(idSet, pageNum) {
  var page = idSet[pageNum],
      mainDeferred = $q.defer(),
      promises = [],
      combinedItems = [];

  for(var i=0; i<page.length; i++){
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    ngGPlacesAPI.placeDetails({placeId: page[i][i]})
      .then(function(data){
        combinedItems.push(data);
        console.log(combinedItems); /// This shows the objects being pushed into the array
        deferred.resolve();
      });

    promises.push(deferred.promise);
  }

  console.log(promises); /// This shows the 10 promises

  $q.all(promises).then(function() { /// Nothing after this line runs
    console.log('test', mainDeferred.promise); /// This logs nothing
    mainDeferred.resolve(combinedItems);
  });
  return mainDeferred.promise;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pretty common error when dealing with async in javascript.

The question should should ask is: "when the resolver (the function you pass to `.then`) looks up the variable `deferred`, what variable does it get back?". Then answer is, they all reference the very last `deferred` you declare.

The problem is, you're declaring `deferred` outside of your resolve function. Remember how javascript looks up variables:

1. Is the variable (in our case, `deferred`) available in the immediate function scope? (in our case, no)
2. Traverse up parent scopes until we find a variable with the given name.

By the time the resolver fires, you've redeclared `deferred` 10 times, each declaration overwriting the previous one! So each time a resolver fires, it actually resolves the *same* `deferred`!

The answer is to wrap your `deferred` declaration in a closure:

```
for(var i=0; i<page.length; i++){
  (function(){
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    ngGPlacesAPI.placeDetails({placeId: page[i][i]})
      .then(function(data){
        combinedItems.push(data);
        console.log(combinedItems); /// This shows the objects being pushed into the array
        deferred.resolve();
      });
    promises.push(deferred.promise);
  })()
}
```

But really, you can simplify your whole program and avoid the deferreds. Let me know if this makes sense to you!:

```
details.getDetails = function(idSet, pageNum) {
  var page = idSet[pageNum];

  // generate an array from 0 to page.length
  var items = Array.apply(null, { length: page.length })

  var promises = items.map(function (i) {
    return ngGPlacesAPI.placeDetails({placeId: page[i][i]});
  })

  return $q.all(promises)
};
```

Comment: Getting rid of the `deferreds` is certainly the right thing to do.  However, personally, I'd find a vanilla loop where you push the promises onto an array to pass to `$q.all` to be much easier to work with than the `Array.apply` + `items.map` solution you've cooked up here.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer. This really helped me to understand and learn some new things. Your second solution especially got my wheels turning an ultimately led me to my answer. @mgilson Thank you also in helping me find my solution. I ended up looping like you mentioned since I had trouble with the index on the array.map

Comment: @mgilson It's probably a matter of code style. I prefer functional iterators, but some people find procedural loops easier to understand. To each their own!