# Calling anonymous functions set in an object, not getting expected result

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to write a modal dialog handler function that is somewhat generic, so I can pass controls to it that handle different actions. It sounds simple, I and thought it would be. I'm trying to pass the button handler functions in an object, which is looped through to register each function to the button click handlers via the ID. It works, but not in the way I expect. Here is the code (requires bootstrap 3):

```
function confirmation(question){
    var modalTitle = 'Confirmation';
    var modalContents = question;
    var modalControls = '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="confirmYes">Confirm</button> <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="confirmNo">Cancel</button>';

    var modalButtons = {
        confirmNo: function(){
            console.log('really, no!');
        },
        confirmYes: function(){
            console.log('really, yes!');
        }
    }

    standardModal(modalTitle,modalContents,modalControls,modalButtons);
}

function standardModal(modalTitle,modalContents,modalControls,modalButtons){
    $('#standardModalTitle').html(modalTitle);
    $('#standardModalBody').html(modalContents);
    $('#standardModalControls').html(modalControls);

    for (var prop in modalButtons){
        if(!modalButtons.hasOwnProperty(prop)) continue;

        $('#'+prop).click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            modalButtons[prop]();
        });
    }

    $('#standardModal').modal('show');
}
```

and here is the HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class='modal fade' tabindex='-1' role='dialog' id='standardModal'>
  <div class='modal-dialog'>
    <div class='modal-content'>
      <div class='modal-header'>
        <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-label='Close'><span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class='modal-title' id='standardModalTitle'></h4>
      </div>
      <div class='modal-body' id='standardModalBody'>

      </div>
      <div class='modal-footer' id='standardModalControls'>
        <button type='button' class='btn btn-default' data-dismiss='modal'>Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I run confirmation('This is a question?'); I should have two buttons in the dialog, Confirm and Cancel. I would expect Confirm to run the modalButtons.confirmYes function, while Cancel should run modalButtons.confirmNo. What is actually happening, is both buttons call the last function defined in modalButtons. If confirmYes is the last function defined, it's run for both buttons.

When I throw console.log statements in there, the variables output are what I expect each time..but the actual function call is wrong.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is this all the code?

Comment: Only thing missing is the includes for twitter bootstrap 3 - but aside from that this code is standalone.

Comment: I cannot get anything to appear hmm...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click a button and `modalButtons[prop]()` gets called, what does `prop` evaluate to? Remember how javascript looks up variable names:

1. If the variable is defined locally, use that value
2. Otherwise, go out 1 scope at a time, until we reach the global (window) scope, and see if a variable with the given name is defined there
3. Otherwise, resolve to `undefined`

In our case, you click the button, then your `click` callback is executed, and javascript tries to look up the value of `prop`:

1. `prop` is not defined in the callback's scope, so it looks at the next outer scope
2. `prop` IS defined in the callback's immediate parent scope! What's the value of `prop`? Well, it's the last value that you looped over (the last element of the array).

What you want to do is define a variable that will always point at the intended value of `prop`. The easiest way to do this is to replace your `for` loop with a functional iterator:

```
Object.keys(modalButtons).forEach(function (prop) {
   // same loop code as before
})
```

The difference is this way, we're declaring a new variable called `prop` in the parent scope, rather than declaring `prop` once and changing its value on every roll of the loop. It's a subtle bug, but something that you'll come up against pretty often, so it's important to understand how this works.

Does that help?

Or see my answer to this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35978389/435124), and let me know if that helps!

Comment: That helped, I wasn't realizing that when click is called later it's just looking at the last defined instance of prop. Thank you!